# HTML5 video - image on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-canvas

I'm trying to capture video frame as image like here:

http://appcropolis.com/using-html5-canvas-to-capture-frames-from-a-video/

My simple code:

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");
var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom"); 


var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

canvas.width  = 500;
canvas.height = 282;

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 500, 282); 

bottom.innerHTML = '';
bottom.appendChild(canvas);
```

On IE it works excellent but on Chrome I've always got black canvas...

Demo here:

http://html5-canvas-test.vipserv.org/

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Tested on Chrome and it works for me.

Comment: @Andrew have you got anywhere with this? I'd be interested to know what the problem is.

Comment: @urbananimal: I've spent few hours on investigation and looks like issue with MP4 files on my Chrome. Appcropolis works for me but only with ogv source. Maybe there is no full html5 canvas support with mp4 videos or bug?

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly in Chrome for me!

**But you need to start the video**, if the video isn't started you'll get a black screen.

Comment: Not for me... Works in chrome canary but not release version.

Comment: @Andrew, I got black screen too. What is your system specs? My Windows7 Home x64, Chrome 22.0.1229.79 m

Comment: My system is Windows 7 and Chrome 22.0.1229.79... tutorial works excellent but my code not

Comment: Im using Windows 7 Professional x64 Chrome Version 22.0.1229.79 m look here: http://www.bilder-space.de/show_img.php?img=72454a-1349697152.png&size=original

Comment: So it looks that my chrome is different and create black square... but why? Adblock, noscript not installed. I've started video before.

Comment: Can you test it in private mode? Chrome is really ugly when Jscript executed once. Sometimes it doesn't want to load the changes...

Comment: Yes, I've tested - no changes. I will check chrome dev version.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the event "seeked" !

```
$(video).seeked(function() {
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 500, 282); 
});
```

Sorry for my English i'm french